# Launching node application on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift

Setting up a node application on openshift and I cannot figure out why it cannot launch, all it keeps coming back is with that port 8080 is in use.

I have ensured that server is listening on both the port and the ip coming from the env variables.

I have another application that does work and the code is basically the same, I have checked on both gears 'cat /etc/services | grep 8080' and they both report 2 instances of webcache.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

"use strict";

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app'),
  debug = require('debug')('landbou:server'),
  http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  models = require("../models");

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */


var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || process.env.NODE_PORT || '5000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    server.listen(port, process.env.NODE_IP);
  } else {
    server.listen(port);
  }

  server.on('error', onError)
    .on('listening', onListening);
});

if (!fs.existsSync('www')) {
  fs.mkdirSync('www');
}

if (!fs.existsSync('www/uploads')) {
  fs.mkdirSync('www/uploads');
}
/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When building service it's always best to base on official openshift template and make sure you are up to date with your version of openshift. In your case problem may be related with invalid environment variables names for port and host.

Take look how to build host and port for openshiftv3 template:
https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex/blob/41661190350421d5dad513c114d3a97612273573/server.js#L11-L12

Comment: Those are the environment variables output by printenv. I can manually hard code any port and it launches error free, connects both to mongo and mysql, the moment it runs on port 8080 it dies.

Comment: Openshift doesn't support manual port setup. 8080 in template is used when running project on local machine. Try using  process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT as in official template

Comment: process.env.NODE_PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT = 8080. 8080 is Openshifts default node port, that is why you need to bind the address as well.